# FF rendering position relative different than all other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website, http://dev.markzanghi.com, is rendering incorrectly in firefox and i don't know why.

Every other browser, including IE renders it correctly.  The link above will display the mistake.  Basically, i need two parts to my header for an animation.  Below is my CSS

```
/*
TOP BAR
*/

.topbar {
height: 75px;
background: url('../img/headerBGtop.png') repeat-x;
}
.bottomTopBar {
background: url('../img/headerBGbottom.png') repeat-x;
height: 6px;
position: relative;
top: 64px;
}
.topbar .headerWrapper {
max-width: 924px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 5px;
}
.bottomHeader {
position: relative;
top: -11px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}
.headerArrowImg {
width: 924px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.bottomFiller {
position: relative;
top: -24px;
background: url(/img/headerBGbottom);
    height: 11px;
}
#leftBottomHeader {
}
#rightBottomHeader {
top: -35px;
}
.logo {
float: left;
margin-top: 13px;
}
.logo img {
height: 55px;
}

.topbarLinks {
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
top: 44px;
z-index: 10;
}

.topbarLinks a{
color: white;
margin-left:25px;
padding: 10px 0px;
}

.topbar .headerArrowImg img {
max-width: none;
position: relative;
left: -200px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="topbar navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="headerWrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#/"><img src="img/homeLogo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="topbarLinks">
                <a id="workLink" href="#"><img src="img/workLink.png" /></a>
                <a id="aboutLink" href="#/about"><img src="img/aboutLink.png" /></a>
                <a id="contactLink" href="#/contact"><img src="img/contactLink.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="bottomHeaderWrap" class="bottomHeader">
                <div class="headerArrowImg">
                    <div id="arrowImgWrapper">
                        <img src="/img/headerArrowImg.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="leftBottomHeader" class="bottomFiller">
        </div>
        <div id="rightBottomHeader" class="bottomFiller">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

If anyone has any idea why this is not working, please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with a menu animation a while back.

The "problem" is that Firefox requires an explicit declaration of both X & Y coordinates when one is declared. On several items you have declared a `top` (Y), but you have not declared a `left` or `right` (X).

Add a `left:0` or something and you should be fine. Or, since they are `position:relative`, you could just convert `top` to `margin-top`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually completely rewrote the code to something more organized, if anyone wants to see it go to dev.markzanghi.com.  Or if this post is past development stages, try www.markzanghi.com.